# Out of memory on large file upload to app service in Azure, cannot reproduce locally

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-appservice

in startup:

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(o =>
{
    o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
});
```

in controller

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestSizeLimit(314572800)] 
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm(Name = "file")]IFormFile file, int sourceId, string title)
        {
            //var file = Request.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault();
            if (file == null || file.Length == 0 /*|| !Regex.Match(file.ContentType, "^audio", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success*/)
            {
                throw new Exception("Bad Audio uploaded");
            }

            if (file.Length > 1024 * 1024 * 300)
            {
                throw new Exception("File size is limited to 300MB");
            }

            long size = file.Length;
            string audioUrlPath;

            FileInfo currentFile = new FileInfo(file. FileName);
            //Hardcoded path due to Gal's request
            string fileName = $"{sourceId}/audio/{Guid.NewGuid()}{currentFile.Extension}";
            audioUrlPath = await m_mediaCloudBlobRepository.SetStreamAsync(file.OpenReadStream(), fileName, BlobContainer.Rss, WebUtils.MPEG_MINTYPE);
            return Ok(new { audioUrlPath, size });
        }
```

314572800 byes (in the RequestSizeLimit annotation) are 300mb.
I tried to upload a file that weights 280mb but got the following exception stack trace:

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
  at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
  at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
  at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
  at System.IO.MemoryStream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.DrainAsync(Stream stream, ArrayPool`1 bytePool, Nullable`1 limit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.InnerReadFormAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.FormValueProviderFactory.AddValueProviderAsync(ValueProviderFactoryContext context)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeValueProvider.CreateAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IList`1 factories)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeValueProvider.CreateAsync(ControllerContext controllerContext)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

in addition, i went to azure app service -> diagnose and solve problems -> Availability and Performance -> Memory Analysis and found the following graph that shows that the app service wasn't at its memory usage pick
[image: azure memory usage graph]

any ideas?

Comment: could you include the actual _code_ handling the file, instead of just the controllers method signature?

Comment: i'll add if you insist but it's not the issue. the stack trace start before reaching my code.